# How to make an infinite loop in GTK

Tags: c, gtk

I want to make a C program with GTK interface that repeatedly update and display the value of a variable (POS) after getting the state of some toggle buttons and pause/sleep for 1 second.

Essentially there are two buttons, UP and DOWN and when UP is pressed, then POS should be updated to POS = POS + 1 and when DOWN is pressed it should be updated to POS = POS - 1.

If both are pressed (they are toggle buttons) then it should return to the same value after going +1 and -1.

After the end of the loop the label (LABEL) should display the POS value and pause for 1 second before starting again.

I did make a minimal working example but I am stuck in making the loop.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *fixed;

  GtkWidget *UP;
  GtkWidget *DOWN;


  GtkWidget *LABEL;
  float POS=0;
  gchar *text;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GtkFixed");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 300);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

  DOWN = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label("DOWN");
  gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), DOWN, 100, 200);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(DOWN, 80, 30);

  UP = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label("UP");
  gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), UP, 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(UP, 80, 30);

  LABEL = gtk_label_new ("0");
  gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), LABEL, 150, 100);

/*This while loop should do but I don't know how to make it run


while TRUE {

if (gtk_toggle_button_get_mode(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(UP))) {
POS = POS + 1.;}

if (gtk_toggle_button_get_mode(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(DOWN))) {
POS = POS - 1.;}

text = g_strdup_printf (" %f ", POS);
gtk_label_set_label (GTK_LABEL(LABEL), text);

sleep(1);
}; */ 


  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", 
  G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
}
```

Comment: Look up the example on how to connect callbacks to signals. And how to use a timer.

Comment: Try `while(1)` or `for(;;)`.

Comment: You have explained what you want your code to do. Now explain what it does instead.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `gtk_main` is already a loop, it runs the main event loop. You then need to think about which event triggers the comportment you want. Clicking a button ? Connect to the "clicked" signal of the button. Timing out? Use `g_timer_add` or `g_timer_add_seconds` to specify in how much time your callback should be called.